# Plotting a Seaborn cumulative histogram with pre-binned data

Tags: seaborn

I am using Seaborn to plot cumulative histograms. One of my data sources provides data pre-binned, and I'd like to plot the data in the same style to match the other histograms. The sample data is like this:

```
     Value  Percentile  TotalCount  1/(1-Percentile)
0    939.0    0.000000           1      1.000000e+00
1   1380.0    0.100000        7504      1.110000e+00
2   1454.0    0.200000       14929      1.250000e+00
3   1492.0    0.300000       22598      1.430000e+00
4   1521.0    0.400000       29865      1.670000e+00
5   1550.0    0.500000       37409      2.000000e+00
...
79  6071.0    0.999982       74560      5.461333e+04
80  6071.0    0.999985       74560      6.553600e+04
81  6071.0    0.999986       74560      7.281778e+04
82  6639.0    0.999988       74561      8.192000e+04
83  6639.0    1.000000       74561               inf
```

The `seaborn.distplot` does not seem to offer any help here. Any work arounds?